# How to fix chakra-ui theme on load input background?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to add theming to a nextjs app, where I am using [chakra-ui](https://next.chakra-ui.com/) but stuck with this issue for a while now.
Right now on load of the `/form` route, the theme is set to light. Once it's changed to dark, it saves the theme to local storage.
`const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode();`
Using this, it's setting the toggel to true, which gives a dark theme.

Once I refresh, I get the theme to dark, as it saved to local storage.

```
const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode();
const isDark = colorMode === 'dark';
 return (
   Switch
     position="fixed"
     top="1rem"
     right="1rem"
     color="green"
     isChecked={isDark}
     onChange={toggleColorMode}
   />
 );
```

Even tho `isDark` is true, still, the Switch is unchecked.

Also, the input field's background is still light, even tho rest of the elements are in dark mode.

What am I doing wrong?

https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-darkness-lypfr

Answer (score 1):

I was using "@chakra-ui/core": "^1.0.0-rc.2". At the time, the latest version is 1.0.0-rc.3.

I had to use `ColorModeScript` just like https://github.com/ljosberinn/personal-react-boilerplate/blob/master/pages/_document.tsx#L70

It started working. Hope it saves someone's day.